# Вектор Xi: скалярное произведение i-й строки на главную диагональ (Python)

Tags: python, матрицы

Хочу получить вектор Xi: скалярное произведение i-й строки матрицы на главную диагональ матрицы, но код выдает ошибку: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'

Вот код

```
def sunction(array):
    ans=[]
    vec=[]
    for i in array:
        for j in i:
            if array.index(i)==i.index(j):
                ans+=[j]
    result = 0
    for i in range(len(m)):
        result += ans[i]*m[i:]
    return ans,result
```

Comment: Несколько нелепо обходить все элементы и искать их индексы, чтобы выбрать диагональ, не так ли? Используйте цикл по индексам и array[i][i]. И что за m? Видимо, список, так зачем вы умножаете число на срез списка???